# C# Windows 10 Bluetooth LE can't connect to server

Tags: c#, windows, windows-10, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing a c# desktop api with forms where I want to receive ACC data from a BLE server und display them in a chart. 
So I'm running in a connection problem and I can't find any solution.
I can find my LE server Device with the watcher.

```
DevicePairingResult dpr = await device.DeviceInformation.Pairing.PairAsync(DevicePairingProtectionLevel.Encryption);
```

returns me "AlreadyPaired"

But when I do

```
device = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(bluetoothAddress: eventArgs.BluetoothAddress);
mGattService = device.GetGattService(MotionService_GUID);
mCharacteristic = mGattService.GetCharacteristics(ACC_Characteristic_GUID)[0];
```

and then

```
var con = device.ConnectionStatus;
```

I receive "Disconnected" in con.

I am bound with de device on windows( I searched for it in Windows and entered the Code)  but I am not connected(based on the Status in the windows info center).
I've read in another Thread in the windows c# developer page that it should not be necessary anymore to pair the device manually.

I'm pretty shure that the rest of my code works because sometimes I can get a connection( pretty confusing for me) and see the right Data in my chart.
Right now I just want to reach a stable connection before changing other part of my code.
Anyone any idea how to solve this?
Thx medTech

Edit:
Here is part of the Code:

Scanning for BLE

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // Create Bluetooth Listener
            var watcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher();

            watcher.ScanningMode = BluetoothLEScanningMode.Active;

            // Register callback for when we see an advertisements
            watcher.Received += OnAdvertisementReceivedAsync;

            // Wait 5 seconds to make sure the device is really out of range
            watcher.SignalStrengthFilter.OutOfRangeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000);
            watcher.SignalStrengthFilter.SamplingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);

            // Starting watching for advertisements
            watcher.Start();
        }
```

Connect to Server:

```
private async void OnAdvertisementReceivedAsync(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs eventArgs)
        {

            // Filter for specific Device
            if (eventArgs.Advertisement.LocalName == "MYDEVICE")
            {
                watcher.Stop();

                var MotionService_GUID = new Guid("00002000-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
                var ACC_Characteristic_GUID = new Guid("00002001-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");


                    device = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(bluetoothAddress: eventArgs.BluetoothAddress);
                    DevicePairingResult dpr = await device.DeviceInformation.Pairing.PairAsync(DevicePairingProtectionLevel.Encryption);
                    mGattService = device.GetGattService(MotionService_GUID);


                    mCharacteristic = mGattService.GetCharacteristics(ACC_Characteristic_GUID)[0];

                    GattDeviceServicesResult result = await device.GetGattServicesAsync();


                    GattCommunicationStatus status1 = await ReadFromCharacteristicAsync(mCharacteristic);

                    var con = device.ConnectionStatus;
                    while (status1 == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            status1 = await ReadFromCharacteristicAsync(mCharacteristic);
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("ERROR");
                            status1 = GattCommunicationStatus.Unreachable;

                        }
                    }

            }
            }
```

Read from Characteristic:

async Task ReadFromCharacteristicAsync(GattCharacteristic mCharacteristic)
        {

```
        GattReadResult readResult = await mCharacteristic.ReadValueAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);

        if (readResult.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[readResult.Value.Length];
            DataReader.FromBuffer(readResult.Value).ReadBytes(data);
            if (chart1.IsHandleCreated)
            {
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { updateChart(data); });
            }

            return readResult.Status;
        }
        return readResult.Status;
    }
```

Terminate Connection

```
 private async Task<bool> ClearBluetoothLEDeviceAsync()
        {

            mCharacteristic.Service.Dispose();
            mGattService.Dispose();
            await device.DeviceInformation.Pairing.UnpairAsync();
            device?.Dispose();
            device = null;
            GC.Collect();
            return true;
        }
```

SO now when I connect the first time to the Server, I only receive zeros which shows me that the there might be a authentication Error.
After that I always receive this Error:
**"System.ArgumentException" in mscorlib.dll** with a notification that there is noch executable Code left because all Threads are doing some asynchronous stuff.
This Error gets thrown when I try to read from the Characteristic.
I never coded in c# before so I am not shure if there is an error in my asynchronous part oder the communication part. 
Thanks you

Comment: Are you sure the devices need pairing? Many BLE devices do not require you to pair them.

Comment: Hi Manfred,
I've had this Problem also without pairing. I unbound and bound my device with windows 10 manually with the given code and my connection worked. But even though I got "Disconnected" as Connectionstatus. This is very confusing to me because in my experience without the handshake between the devices and without having a connection I receive the right amound of data but only zeros as value. So I thought the connection state is a parameter where I can confirm that my connection is succesfull.

Answer (score 0):

Pairing is not the same as connecting!
I really advise using the BLE-advertisementWatcher to select  and connect to your device.
The reason is that many BLE-devices don't save their pairing status.
In windows  device-watcher once paired, the device stays paired even if it is switched off or out of reach. 
Also many times the connection status is kept, unless the device is unpaired and disposed in code or removed in windows settings.

All BLE-devices that I know of start advertising as soon as there is no connection for some time. 
This time depends on the device, but most of the time within seconds.

So don't pair but just connect if the device is advertising.

Comment: Hey GrooverFromHooland,
thank you for your answer. I am using an Advertisement watcher
 `var watcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher();`
I can find my device alle the time, also if I did not connect it to windows manually. 
At the end of the connection I do ` mCharacteristic.Service.Dispose();
            mGattService.Dispose();
            device?.Dispose();
            device = null;
            GC.Collect();`
to remove the ble stack completely.
But after the first connection, I either receive only zeros as value or my app stop because in Readoperation is no executable code.

Comment: There is a lot doubt if I go through your code, but the most worrying is the using of  while (status1 == GattCommunicationStatus.Success). this means reading over and over. You have to wait for the result. Use if instead.